# jQuery third row first cell selector animate blink

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to blink a table cell content without attributes. But this doesn't work:

```
var tdnode = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[2].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

$(tdnode).animate({backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }, 500);
$(tdnode).animate({backgroundColor: "white" }, 500);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery comes with the ability to select  elements by index using the [:eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

`$('tr:eq(2) td:eq(0)')` would select the first cell of the third row within a table.

Include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) for color animation, jQuery alone doesn't ship with that ability.

Chaining methods together avoids unnecessary selectors when acting on the same element

```js
$('tr:eq(2) td:eq(0)')
  .animate({backgroundColor: "#ff0000" }, 500)
  .animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1-1</td>
    <td>1-2</td>
    <td>1-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2-1</td>
    <td>2-2</td>
    <td>2-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3-1</td>
    <td>3-2</td>
    <td>3-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Here is some documentation regarding [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)